# Render React component in Preact?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I try to use Preact for most of my projects but now I have a requirement to use a React component. I don't want this to require me to switch frameworks. Is there anything I can do to render the React component from my Preact code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preact provides a compatibility layer called [`preact-compat`](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat).

You can use your module bundler to alias `react` and `react-dom` imports to use `preact-compat`, and this should allow you to use React code in your Preact app unmodified.

Here is a Webpack example, taken from the `preact-compat` docs:

```js
{
    // ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': 'preact-compat',
            'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
            // Not necessary unless you consume a module using `createClass`
            'create-react-class': 'preact-compat/lib/create-react-class',
            // Not necessary unless you consume a module requiring `react-dom-factories`
            'react-dom-factories': 'preact-compat/lib/react-dom-factories'
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Edit:** As noted by @pmkro in the comments, [from Preact 10.0 onwards](https://github.com/developit/preact/releases/tag/10.0.0-alpha.0), `preact-compat` is being moved back into the core `preact` package, and will be available via `preact/compat`.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Just as a note this is changing with `preact 10`. This is valid for `8.x` but for X its changed to `preact/compat` and it ships with the rest of the package.

Comment: Thank you for the update @pmkro - have been out of the Preact world for a little while so I wasn't aware. Will update my answer :)